# Can you open an Access 2007 database with Sharepoint 2010 Foundation

Tags: access-denied

We have the new Sharepoint Foundation 2010 (the free version). I would like to add an Access database to the library and have the ability to open it in the Sharepoint site with Access 2007. After I upload the database into the Sharepoint site and try to use the 'open with access' on the ribbon, the option is grayed out.

My question is there something I need to enable on the server to be able to have this option available? Or do I need to have Access 2010 on my computer in order to open a database on my sharepoint site, which means Access 2007 does not allow me to do this?

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is Access Services which is an Enterprise (the paid version) feature, per Microsoft's own [Comparison Chart](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/buy/Pages/Editions-Comparison.aspx)